# How do I format my function to call a templated class?

Tags: c++, function, templates, reference

I'm sure there is a very easy answer, but I can't figure it out. I have written a templated class, but I want to pass that class by reference in a class function that isn't templated. Heres what I have. I get a bunch of errors. All I need to do is figure how to format the way to insert templated class into function, but I'm at a lost. Thank you and sorry if the code doesn't really help you out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    insert(const T& Item)
    //And other function, just examples
};

class noFoo(){
void test(Foo <T>& foo);
int i;
int j;
int k
};

template <typename T>
void noFoo::test(Food <T>& foo)}
cout << "hi";
}
int main() {
    Foo<char> wr;
    test(wr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try function template?

Comment: @crook Sorry I did, I just forgot to add it in this post.

Answer (score 2):

Make `test` a function template.  I also corrected loads of syntax errors for you (`class noFoo()`?), removed unnecessary code, and ran `clang-format` for indentation.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Foo {};

class noFoo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void test(Foo<T> &);
};

template <typename T>
void noFoo::test(Foo<T> &)
{
    std::cout << "hi\n";
}

int main()
{
    Foo<char> wr;
    noFoo{}.test(wr);
}
```

---

Since your question is tagged [d](/questions/tagged/d), here the same code in D.

```d
import std.stdio;

class Foo(T) {};

class noFoo
{
public:
    void test(T)(Foo!(T))
    {
        writeln("hi");
    }
};

void main()
{
    auto wr = new Foo!char;
    (new noFoo).test(wr);
}
```

Comment: Adding a couple of other ways to call `test` - `noFoo nf; nf.test(wr);` OR `noFoo().test(wr);`

Comment: In D, passing a class by ref is usually wrong (Objects are already a ref under the hood, so `ref SomeClass` is like a `SomeClass**` in C) and there's no need for the ; at the end of the class definition. just fyi

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Good catch!  That was a leftover from when I initially implemented it in terms of structs.